# UIPrintInteractionController doesn't show localized text

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

`UIPrintInteractionController` only shows in English language when the language is Chinese.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xcode, select your project, in project info tab, go to [Localizations] section, add [Chinese] language.

Comment: Thanks,for the reply .i am implementing the Dynamic Localization so i forgot to add the localization files to project. Answer accepted..